# сложный запрос в базу mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

здравствуйте, есть две таблицы:

```
`oc_vendor` (
 `vendor_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `vproduct_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `ori_country` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `product_cost` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
 `shipping_method` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `prefered_shipping` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `shipping_cost` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
 `vtotal` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
 `product_url` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `vendor` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `wholesale` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `date_add` datetime NOT NULL,
```

и вторая:

```
`oc_vendors` (
 `vendor_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `vendor_name` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `commission_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `product_limit_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `company` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `company_id` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `vendor_description` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `telephone` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `fax` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `paypal_email` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `iban` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `bank_name` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `bank_address` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `swift_bic` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `tax_id` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `accept_paypal` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
 `accept_cheques` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
 `accept_bank_transfer` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
 `store_url` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `vendor_image` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `firstname` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `lastname` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `address_1` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `address_2` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `city` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `postcode` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `zone_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `sort_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `date_add` datetime NOT NULL,
```

можно ли одним сложным запросом сделать выборку из этих двух, если можно то как??? а выбрать нужно vendor_name, vendor_description, vendor_image, firstname, lastname from oc_vendors where vproduct_id = '.$product_id 
где $product_id - id продукта в таблице oc_vendor  ???

Comment: жойном моно `left join` к примеру

Comment: Это можно сделать только _простым_ запросом. Потому что склейка двух таблиц в запросе - это базовый уровень знаний языка SQL.Даже учебники читать не обязательно. просто поглядеть примеры запросов хотя бы на этом сайте в вопросах. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B

Comment: Как именно?? Если не трудно! Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле все оказалось проще чем я думал. Запрос выглядит так:

```
Select vendor_name, firstname, lastname, ...
From vendors, vendor
where vendors.vendor_id=vendor.vendor and vendor.vproduct_id=product_id
```

Всем спасибо )

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, то у вас в таблице нет `oc_vendors` нет поля ассоциации с таблицей `oc_vendor` а оно должно быть для работы любого запроса для двух и более таблиц. В случае если бы у вас было поле в таблице `oc_vendors` (назовем его например **id_ven_to_venders** ) запрос можно было бы составить например так:

```
SELECT vendor_name, vendor_description, vendor_image, firstname, lastname Where id_ven_to_venders ='.$product_id.'
```

поле по которому происходит ассоциация таблиц должно иметь такое же значение как и ассоциируемая запись из другой таблицы.. я не очень понимаю логику ваших таблиц и что в них храниться и как перекликается, но если предположить что 1 вендору из таблицы `oc_vendor` принадлежат несколько  других (записей) из таблицы `oc_vendors` наше поле **id_ven_to_venders** должно было бы содержать значения `vendor_id` из таблицы `oc_vendor` ( соответственно задавая ассоциацию 1 к 1 или 1 ко многим )

З.Ы. семантика таблиц ужасная, я могу ошибаться но понять по название полей и таблиц что они содержат крайне затруднительно, рекомендую называть таблицы, поля и переменные максимально доступно и отлично от других иначе легко запутаться и вам и разработчикам который будут поддерживать ваш код